# How to create an AngularCli application that contains another AngularCli inside?

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-mvc-3, angular-cli

I have an application in development that is in Angular2 using AngularCli, and I want to use it as a "Layout" (like a MasterPage) to another project. Like a big "SPA System".

For example, in the menu we will have the following:

- Framework

  - Page A
- Xpto

  - Page B

The Framework is running in http://localhost:90 and XPTO is running in http://localhost:91. Both of them is running on AngularCli.

I want to create a structure that when I click on Page A or Page B, the browser doesn't reload and it will give an "app" style to the user, loading the page as a SPA ACROSS the sites.

The main reason is to reuse the Javascripts, CSS and many other files from de "Framework" project to other 20 projects. I don't want to replicate all the components, files and etc across those projects.

Today we use MVC3 and the RazorGenerator to create .cshtml as a DLL to reuse the .cshtml from Framework to other modules.

But we want go AngularCli. Is there any way to do that ? If it isn't, is there some way to create a template in AngularCli that can be reused the components and the other files ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put shared Angular components and modules into a separate npm package and use this package as a dependency for other projects.
In order to reference your npm package (I assume it's not hosted at npmjs.com) you can specify a git repository or local path.
Here is an example of package.json

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "my_git_package": "git+ssh://user@hostname/project.git#commit-ish",
    "my_local_package": "file:../foo/bar"
  }
}
```

Take a look at `dependencies` section here https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

Comment: Hi Random, thanks for your answer. I'm searching how to do that but when I do npm publish, the package goes to internet ? Do you have some example how to do that ? 

Thanks again !

Comment: Hi, added an example to my response