# Angular 4+ Assistance: Sharing Services across projects

Tags: git, angular, npm

I'm fairly new to Angular 4+.  We now have an angular 4+ app in production.  It went well enough where another app is now desired.

Some of the original app will be needed in the new app, primarily in the service area (e.g. logging, auth, config).

I'm not sure how to go about breaking these services out into a more cross-project shareable entity.  Is there a good guide to making shared services into an NPM module?  Is that overkill and should I do something similar, like git submodules?  I haven't found a good resource on this topic.

Comment: In order to minimize my dependency issues, I'm thinking it may be easiest to include the shared .ts files into the consuming project.  I'm certain this is doable using Git submodules or subtrees.  I'm guessing it's not possible with a tool like NPM, as an NPM package is likely a self-contained functional entitity (not something that needs to be compiled by the consuming project)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm certain that where I landed on this isn't the most proper.  That said, I didn't want to over engineer in my case to simply share some JS code across projects.

I ended up just creating a git repo that holds the shared JS.  Then in the consuming repo I use subtree commands to push/pull a sub-directory of JS from the consuming repo into/out of the shared repo.  Then other projects can do the same as needed, and branches can be used in the shared repo to manage versioning if needed.

What this ends up creating for me is a /lib directory that's outside the normal /src directory.  However, in my tsconfig.json file I pulled the /lib JS in and am compiling it with /src:

```
"include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "lib/**/*.ts"
  ],
```

This ends up with a very simply way to pull out common JS files, have them in a separate repo for sharing purposes, and compile them into each consuming project as if they were in the project itself.  No need to mess with NPM packages, dependencies, etc.  Some of the git commands in case this interests you:

Set up a remote to the shared repo:

```
git remote add -f SHARED_JS_REMOTE <Your Shared Repo URL Here>
```

Add the shared repo into the consuming project:

```
git subtree add --prefix=lib/shared-js SHARED_JS_REMOTE master
```

Push changes from consuming repo back to the shared repo:

```
git fetch SHARED_JS_REMOTE master
git subtree push --prefix=lib/shared-js SHARED_JS_REMOTE master
```

Pull changes from shared repo back into consuming repo:

```
git fetch SHARED_JS_REMOTE master
git subtree pull --prefix=lib/shared-js SHARED_JS_REMOTE master
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a good question which is more about a way of structuring your projects.
And you've **already** mentioned two possible solutions in your answer.

**Solution #1: NPM library**

Quite common practice to separate reusable components of your system to the library. Especially for the enterprise systems, it is a convenient way to have helpers libraries to reuse across projects. (Could be hosted in the private npm or directly on the private git).

P.S. Basically git submodules is not really different from hosting your service as a library. As long as you are doing link to another project through the git, and you will need to install and build it. Exactly what you are doing while keeping dependency in the `package.json` file.

**Solution #2: Monorepo**

Also, the popular solution became famous because of large companies like Google, Facebook etc. Keeping all your projects in the single repo, so you definitely can reuse any of your services/components across projects.

**Conclusion**

Making a decision should depend on the amount of code you are going to share and complexity of it.

From your question, I understood that you will need just small blocks to build your projects. I would suggest building general **components based library**. So you can `import` from it components & services which you need in your projects. The down-side of this approach is testing. Once you will update library version, you will need to make sure nothing breaks after.

**Monorepo** could give you some advantages in terms of delivering fast and safe code each time you will need to change some core services. If all your code is in the one repo, it's obviously easier to make changes and run tests for all projects in the single place. But flexibility and *release* process of projects could become a big pain in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Mikki - very helpful.  I'll dive into these options a bit deeper.  I've since found quite a few folks requesting library/packaging support in Angular 4+, with a handful of partial solutions, but no smoking gun great options. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1692 as well as the followup: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6510

Comment: I've seen solution with dependency to module repository, but no good documentation for this way
`"dependencies": {
   "shared-module": "git+ssh://git@github.com:user/shared-module.git#develop"
 }`

Comment: @Saram here is something you're talking about: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43215690/1828986